# Final Design / Look Of The Site

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

We should probably be having a conversation regarding the final look of the site. This (probably) hinges a bit on the domain that we select, however a common theme amongst the current favorites is HTTP status codes.

This (hopefully) encourages more people to get involved in coming up with the domain name, as well as discussing what our 'final look' will be.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be posting about the design ideas for the Webmasters site soon!

Comment: I can't wait to see what you cooked up :)

Answer (score 0):

Ask graphicdesigners.stackexchange.com ... oh wait. It's not live yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite dark. ... Don't know if this is a good or bad thing, but still.